# Using graph generator with a custom class as node

Tags: python, networkx

I'd like to use some of the built-in graph generators, but with a custom python class as the nodes instead of integers. What's the best approach for this? Should I add the custom class as an attribute?

For example, here I generate a complete graph with integers as nodes:

```
import networkx as nx
K_5 = nx.complete_graph(5)
```

And here I create a single agent, which I would like to use as a node instead of integers:

```
from agents import Agent
agent = Agent()
```

I wonder if the answer to this involves creating a network and then relabeling the nodes with `nx.relabel_nodes()`.

Comment: please post your current code

Comment: @shavenwarthog, okay, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Networkx seems to really want to use IDs, not concrete objects.  However your idea is correct -- we can use `relabel_nodes()` to convert numbers to object instances.

Demo:

### source

```
import networkx as nx

class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Agent #{}>'.format(self.id)


g = nx.complete_graph(5)
print g.nodes()

nx.relabel_nodes(g, mapping=Agent, copy=False)
print g.nodes()
```

### output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[<Agent #1>, <Agent #3>, <Agent #0>, <Agent #4>, <Agent #2>]
```